# Why is ListView scroll not working inside Grid?

Tags: .net, xaml

How come the ListView scroll is not working when nested in the Grid ?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Person}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Id}" Header="Id" Width="100"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" Width="Auto" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
 <Grid>
```

Comment: A ListView scrolls vertically by default, when its actual width is less than the width of its content. You've probably put it in a Panel that doesn't resize it.

Comment: Get rid of any parent StackPanels and the scrolling should work without you having to touch any ScrollViewer attached properties.

Comment: @Clemens Did you mean "Horizontally", or "height"?  Either way, I think you got your axis mixed up halfway through your comment.

Comment: @BradleyUffner No, I mean vertically. But I confused width and height... But a ListView of course also scrolls horizontally.

Comment: @mm8 I managed to find the problem, the ListView was nested inside a Grid Row with "Auto" height. Changed from "Auto" to a value , like 150 and now it works. Thank you !

Answer (score -1):

Solution is to change the Grid row height from "Auto" to a specific value , for example 150 . Scroll should work is your list contains enough elements to activate the scroll.

Solution :

```
Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Person}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Id}" Header="Id" Width="100"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" Width="Auto" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
 <Grid>
```